# to_timetamp not showing milliseconds in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

My version of spark in 2.4.5. And in looking through the posts in this site, it is supposed to show milliseconds.
However when I try to convert a column `TIME_STAMP` that is of type `string` to `timestamp` with milliseconds, I get `null` values.

```
df.withColumn('TIME_STAMP_1', to_timestamp('TIME_STAMP', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'))
```

This is the result:

```
+-------+-------+--------------------------+------------+
|SEQ_ID |TOOL_ID|TIME_STAMP                |TIME_STAMP_1|
+-------+-------+--------------------------+------------+
|2747469|6019   |2020-09-06 11:56:46.395000|null        |
|3101736|6019   |2020-09-06 11:56:46.395000|null        |
|2747474|6019   |2020-09-06 11:56:46.395000|null        |
|3101745|6019   |2020-09-06 11:56:46.395000|null        |
|3077475|6019   |2020-09-06 11:56:46.395000|null        |
+-------+-------+--------------------------+------------+
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `null` because your timestamp is of format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`
Use `cast("timestamp")` instead of using `to_timestamp()` and specifying the format:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn('TIME_STAMP_1', col('TIME_STAMP').cast("timestamp")).show(truncate=False)
+-------+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|SEQ_ID |TOOL_ID|TIME_STAMP                |TIME_STAMP_1              |
+-------+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|2747469|6019   |2020-09-06 11:56:46.395000|2020-09-06 11:56:46.395   |
|2747469|6019   |2020-09-06 11:56:46.395001|2020-09-06 11:56:46.395001|
+-------+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Interesting, I tried `to_timestamp('TIME_STAMP', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'))` but it still gave me `null`. However the `cast` worked. Thank You!